# Nuxtjs taking scripts from wrong url

Tags: nuxt.js

Found a problem with nuxtjs, i added subdomain to my application to test some new features before the production.
So my "test" application making request to application.com/_nuxt/script.js not to test.application.com/_nuxt/script.js.

I changed config to test application, but it's not working.

```js
build: {
  publicPath: https://test.application.com/_nuxt,
}
```

Comment: When is it not working? Did you do a rebuild? Are your various endpoints up to date? Is it `yarn dev` that is not working locally? Maybe some cache?

Comment: That definitely not cache, it's started with .env.test so everything is cool, rebuild is not helping.

Comment: My apology, that was my fault, trouble was inside my ci/cd file, i copied wrong .env file

Answer (score 1):

The error was coming from a mistaken copy-pasta. Happens. :D

Nothing wrong with [publicPath](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#publicpath) so far.